# ASP.NET Core Web Api post request 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net, post, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, asp.net-core-webapi

I have post method in the controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ICompanyService _companyService;

        public CompanyController(ICompanyService companyService)
        {
            _companyService = companyService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("saveParameters")]
        public StatusCodeResult  SaveCompanyValuationParameters([FromBody] CompanyValuationParametersDTO cvpDto)
        {
            var userName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var cvpDto1 = new CompanyValuationParametersDTO(27, 5, 4,
                5, 5, 5, userName);
            _companyService.SaveCompanyValuationParameters(cvpDto1);

            return StatusCode(201);
            //return CreatedAtAction("SaveCompanyValuationParameters", new { id = cvpDto1.Id }, cvpDto1);
        }
}
```

the body of the method is a complete mess now but I just want to make it work. I've tried several routes and return types like StatusCodeResult, ActionResult, void but still I can't reach this method from postman:
[image]
So how to reach the post method from postman? I think I am missing something simple but still can't figure out what exactly it is.

DTO:

```
    public class CompanyValuationParametersDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public int ProfessionalGrowth  { get; set; }
        public int CompanyBenefits  { get; set; }
        public int CommunicationWithColleagues  { get; set; }
        public int EducationSector  { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding {} brackets to json in postman ?

Comment: @Raik I recieve 400 Bad request then

Comment: That's okay, beacuse it means it found something. Do you have any logs or exception when Bad Request occurs ?

Comment: Maybe you dont have ICompanyService registered ?

Comment: @Raik I've added brackets and changed method somehow and it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Raik. If you don't add {} to JSON, the error will be 'Bad Request' and not '404 Not Found'.

Comment: @Raik. If the ICompanyService not registered the error will be 'Internal Server Error' and not '404 Not Found'

Comment: @Iman Bahrampour You never know, maybe he have some custom logic. Brackets and ICompanyService was the only ideas i had.

Comment: @Raik. ok, we don't know what he writes but I said if the error is related to custom logic the error is an internal server and not '404'. the 404 error occurs when the URL can't be found.

Comment: @ImanBahrampour If you have custom logic you can return any status code.

Comment: @Raik. We are speaking about this question. do you see 404 status code in this question?!

Comment: @ImanBahrampour Not in example, but we dont have any information about Filters and other things. So i assume anything, just beeing open minded.

Comment: @Raik. We are on a different wavelength dude. good luck